# Symlink Sublime Text 2 Settings - Other Machines (Windows)

Tags: command-line, sublimetext2, sublimetext, symlink

I got my Sublime Text 2 Settings to symlink from dropbox on my first machine (laptop). I am now trying to get my second machine to read those setttings using the instructions at

https://packagecontrol.io/docs/syncing#dropbox-windows

I am mostly having trouble with this command

`cmd /c mklink /D User $env:userprofile\Dropbox\Sublime\User`

I am running

`cmd /c mklink /D User c:\Users\Ross Dallaire\Dropbox\Sublime\User`

and getting

`The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

Comment: Did you try running `cmd /c mklink /D User $env:userprofile\Dropbox\Sublime\User`?

Comment: That seemed to work and setup the symlink. However the settings aren't working and when I go to the folder I get
`The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Comment: Is your Dropbox set up **exactly** as described in the instructions? If your `User` folder is in a different directory, then of course the command won't work.

Comment: Dropbox is set as C:\Users\Ross Dallaire\Dropbox\Sublime\User

Comment: Got it, looks like its an issue with the spacing in my name as the folder. Thanks @MattDMo

`cmd /c mklink /D User "c:\Users\Ross Dallaire\Dropbox\Sublime\User"`